# Jquery - detect focus by class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, focus

I'm trying to detect when an input tag is selected, trying to catch its class name.
For example,

```
<input id="aa1" class="bbb"  style="height: 30px; width: 100%"/>
<input id="aa2" class="bbb"  style="height: 30px; width: 100%"/>
<input id="aa3" class="bbb"  style="height: 30px; width: 100%"/>
```

In my javascript I want to detect when an input with a class is selected. For that I'm doing:

```
    $(".bbb").focus(function () { 

        var row_id = $(this.id);
    });
```

This jQuery focus method is only reached if the first input (id="aa1") is selected.. All the others are not detected..

Why? Can you help me? How do I solve this?

Thank you,
Best Regards,
William.

Comment: What do you expect `$(this.id)` to do? When you focus the first input, it's `$("aa1")`, which won't return anything because that selects an element like `<aa1>`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not work, becouse you selector is wrong, try:

```
$(".bbb").focus(function () { 
    var row_id = this.id;
    alert(row_id);
});
```

[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/d85pt8fp/1/)

Answer (score 0):

For accessing an attribute using jQuery, you should use [`attr()`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) as follows:

```
$(".bbb").focus(function () { 
    var row_id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

*(`$(this.id);` will search for elements with their tagname matching `this.id`)*